# Can we create type erasing weak references with non-optional properties in Swift?

Tags: swift

### Some background

Type erasing containers are useful structures in Swift given it's current inability to support passing generic type parameters. There are some good explanation of this from the community:

- http://www.russbishop.net/type-erasure
- https://realm.io/news/tryswift-gwendolyn-weston-type-erasure/
- https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/

Here's an example:

```
protocol View: class {
    associatedtype ViewModel: Equatable

    var viewModel: ViewModel! { get set }

    func render(_ viewModel: ViewModel)
}

class _AnyViewBoxBase<T: Equatable>: View {

    var viewModel: T!

    func render(_ viewModel: T) {
        fatalError()
    }
}

final class _ViewBox<Base: View>: _AnyViewBoxBase<Base.ViewModel> {

    var base: Base!

    override var viewModel: Base.ViewModel! {
        get {
            return base.viewModel
        }
        set {
            base.viewModel = newValue
        }
    }

    init(_ base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }

    override func render(_ viewModel: Base.ViewModel) {
        base.render(viewModel)
    }
}

final class AnyView<T: Equatable>: View {

    var _box: _AnyViewBoxBase<T>

    var viewModel: T! {
        get {
            return _box.viewModel
        }
        set {
            _box.viewModel = newValue
        }
    }

    func render(_ viewModel: T) {
        _box.render(viewModel)
    }

    init<Base: View>(_ base: Base) where Base.ViewModel == T {
        _box = _ViewBox(base)
    }
}

struct ExampleViewModel {
    let content: String
}

extension ExampleViewModel: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: ExampleViewModel, rhs: ExampleViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.content == rhs.content
    }
}

final class Example: View {
    var viewModel: ExampleViewModel!

    init(viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func render(_ viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
    }
}
```

These type erasing boxes allow us to construct generic containers or create properties which must conform to a generic protocol with a specific type but are not restricted to a concrete implementation. For example using an `AnyView` below I can easily swap in a view test double.

```
struct TypeUnderTest {
    var view: AnyView<ExampleViewModel>
}

var example = Example(viewModel: ExampleViewModel(content: "hello"))
var instanceUnderTest = TypeUnderTest(view: AnyView(example))
```

---

So far so good. I could similarly define `View` to have an optional or non-optional (rather than implicitly unwrapped optional) `viewModel` property and update by boxes accordingly.

### However what if I want my type erased property to be a *weak* reference?

`weak var view: AnyView<ExampleViewModel>` is no good. That would leave me with only a weak reference to by box type and it would be immediately deallocated.

`var view: WeakAnyView<ExampleViewModel>` get's us closer. We can create a box which weakly references it's contents. If our `View` protocol only defines optional properties then we're good to go:

```
protocol View: class {
    associatedtype ViewModel: Equatable

    var viewModel: ViewModel? { get set }

    func render(_ viewModel: ViewModel)
}

class _AnyViewBoxBase<T: Equatable>: View {

    var viewModel: T?

    func render(_ viewModel: T) {
        fatalError()
    }
}

final class _ViewBox<Base: View>: _AnyViewBoxBase<Base.ViewModel> {

    weak var base: Base?

    override var viewModel: Base.ViewModel? {
        get {
            return base?.viewModel
        }
        set {
            base?.viewModel = newValue
        }
    }

    init(_ base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }

    override func render(_ viewModel: Base.ViewModel) {
        base?.render(viewModel)
    }
}

final class AnyView<T: Equatable>: View {

    var _box: _AnyViewBoxBase<T>

    var viewModel: T? {
        get {
            return _box.viewModel
        }
        set {
            _box.viewModel = newValue
        }
    }

    func render(_ viewModel: T) {
        _box.render(viewModel)
    }

    init<Base: View>(_ base: Base) where Base.ViewModel == T {
        _box = _ViewBox(base)
    }
}

struct ExampleViewModel {
    let content: String
}

extension ExampleViewModel: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: ExampleViewModel, rhs: ExampleViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.content == rhs.content
    }
}

final class Example: View {
    var viewModel: ExampleViewModel?

    init(viewModel: ExampleViewModel?) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func render(_ viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
    }
}

struct TypeUnderTest {
    var view: AnyView<ExampleViewModel>
}

let viewModel = ExampleViewModel(content: "hello")
var example: Example? = Example(viewModel: viewModel)
let instanceUnderTest = TypeUnderTest(view: AnyView(example!))
instanceUnderTest.view.viewModel
example = nil
instanceUnderTest.view.viewModel
```

---

However if my erased protocol (`View`) defines non-optional properties then we have a problem. `_ViewBox` must define a non-optional `viewModel` to conform to `View` but that forces us to ignore the very real possibility that our weakly referenced boxed type will have been deallocated and we don't have a safe way to communicate this to a caller.

One option is to add yet another box but this is just becoming painful to use:

```
protocol View: class {
    associatedtype ViewModel: Equatable

    var viewModel: ViewModel { get set }

    func render(_ viewModel: ViewModel)
}

class _AnyViewBoxBase<T: Equatable>: View {

    var viewModel: T

    func render(_ viewModel: T) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init(viewModel: T) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var empty: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
    }
}

final class _ViewBox<Base: View>: _AnyViewBoxBase<Base.ViewModel> {

    weak var base: Base?

    override var viewModel: Base.ViewModel {
        get {
            return base!.viewModel
        }
        set {
            base?.viewModel = newValue
        }
    }

    init(_ base: Base) {
        super.init(viewModel: base.viewModel)
        self.base = base
    }

    override func render(_ viewModel: Base.ViewModel) {
        base?.render(viewModel)
    }

    override var empty: Bool {
        get {
            return base == nil
        }
    }
}

final class AnyView<T: Equatable>: View {

    var _box: _AnyViewBoxBase<T>

    var viewModel: T {
        get {
            return _box.viewModel
        }
        set {
            _box.viewModel = newValue
        }
    }

    func render(_ viewModel: T) {
        _box.render(viewModel)
    }

    init<Base: View>(_ base: Base) where Base.ViewModel == T {
        _box = _ViewBox(base)
    }

    var empty: Bool {
        return _box.empty
    }
}

struct AnyViewOptionalBox<T: Equatable> {

    private var _view: AnyView<T>?
    var view: AnyView<T>? {
        get {
            if let view = self._view, view.empty == false {
                return view
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            self._view = newValue
        }
    }

    init(view: AnyView<T>) {
        self.view = view
    }
}

struct ExampleViewModel {
    let content: String
}

extension ExampleViewModel: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: ExampleViewModel, rhs: ExampleViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.content == rhs.content
    }
}

final class Example: View {
    var viewModel: ExampleViewModel

    init(viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func render(_ viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
    }
}

struct TypeUnderTest {
    var viewBox: AnyViewOptionalBox<ExampleViewModel>
}

let viewModel = ExampleViewModel(content: "hello")
var example: Example? = Example(viewModel: viewModel)
let anyView: AnyView<ExampleViewModel> = AnyView(example!)
let anyViewOptional: AnyViewOptionalBox<ExampleViewModel> = AnyViewOptionalBox(view: anyView)
let instanceUnderTest = TypeUnderTest(viewBox: anyViewOptional)
instanceUnderTest.viewBox.view?.viewModel.content
example = nil
instanceUnderTest.viewBox.view?.viewModel.content
```

---

Is there a better way to maintain a weak reference to a type erased property?

Comment: Apologies for the long code samples but at least you can drop these all in to a playground to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you want is to link the life-cycle of the type-erased box to the life-cycle of the object it contains, such that the box gets deallocated as soon as the contained object gets deallocated.

One way to do that is to ensure the box only weakly references the contained object and make the box an associated object of the contained object using objc_setAssociatedObject(...). This way you basically invert the ownership relation between the two objects.

See the playground sample below:

```
import ObjectiveC

protocol View: class {
    associatedtype ViewModel: Equatable

    var viewModel: ViewModel { get set }

    func render()
}

private var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

final class AnyView<T: Equatable>: View {

    let _viewModelGetter: () -> T
    let _viewModelSetter: (T) -> Void
    let _render: () -> Void

    init<Base: View>(_ base: Base) where Base.ViewModel == T {
        //Ensure this object doesn't reference base, so there is no retain cycle
        _viewModelGetter = { [weak base] in
            //You can force unwrap, because it is guaranteed that base is not deallocated because of the association
            return base!.viewModel
        }
        _viewModelSetter = { [weak base] in
            //You can force unwrap, because it is guaranteed that base is not deallocated because of the association
            base!.viewModel = $0
        }
        _render = { [weak base] in
            //You can force unwrap, because it is guaranteed that base is not deallocated because of the association
            base!.render()
        }

        //Associate this object with the base, so it gets deallocated when base gets deallocated, also base is guaranteed to exist during our lifetime
        objc_setAssociatedObject(base, &AssociatedObjectHandle, self, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }

    deinit {
        print("dealloc: \(self)")
    }

    var viewModel: T {
        get {
            return _viewModelGetter()
        }
        set {
            _viewModelSetter(newValue)
        }
    }

    func render() {
        _render()
    }
}

class ConcreteView: View {
    typealias ViewModel = String

    var viewModel: String

    init(viewModel: String) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    deinit {
        print("dealloc: \(self)")
    }

    func render() {
        print("viewModel: \(viewModel)")
    }
}


weak var anyView: AnyView<String>?
autoreleasepool {
    var concreteView = ConcreteView(viewModel: "Test")
    autoreleasepool {
        anyView = AnyView(concreteView)

        //Any view should render correctly because concrete view exists
        anyView!.render()
    }
    //Success: anyView is not nil yet, because concreteView still exists
    anyView!.render()
}
//Crash: anyView is now nil
anyView!.render()
```

Output:

```
viewModel: Test
viewModel: Test
dealloc: __lldb_expr_34.ConcreteView
dealloc: __lldb_expr_34.AnyView<Swift.String>
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```